# Best index/document structure for ElasticSearch/OpenSearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm new to ElasticSearch/OpenSearch and I'm trying to figure out the best way to organize indices and document structure for my use case. I would like to render some stats from my application on a dashboard, so I plan to send some important events from my application to ElasticSearch/OpenSearch directly.

I've analyzed the application and decided that I would have the following events (documents):

```json
{
  "type": "api.request",
  "method": "{method-name}",
  "timestamp": "{timestamp}"
}
```

Based on `api.request` event I would like to know how many API requests are performed in some specific time range, e.g. RPS.

```json
{
  "type": "page.rendered",
  "name": "{page-name}",
  "duration": "{render-duration}",
  "timestamp": "{timestamp}"
}
```

Based on `page.rendered` event I would like to know what pages are accessed by the users the most and how fast the pages are getting rendered, e.g. I would like to know if some pages are slow to render so I would be able to optimize their performance.

```json
[
  {
    "type": "user.created",
    "userId": "{uuidv4}",
    "timestamp": "{timestamp}"
  },
  {
    "type": "user.invited",
    "userId": "{uuidv4}",
    "referrerId": "{uuidv4}",
    "timestamp": "{timestamp}"
  }
]
```

Based on `user.created` and `user.invited` events I would like to know how many users are registered and invited each day, how many users are invited and how many users are registered directly without invitation.

```json
{
  "type": "user.invitation-failed",
  "userId": "{uuidv4}",
  "error": "{error-name}",
  "timestamp": "{timestamp}"
}
```

Based on `user.invitation-failed` event I would like to know what causing invitations to fail (there are various reason for this), so I would like to see a percentage for each error name.

```json
{
  "type": "user.photo-uploaded",
  "userId": "{uuidv4}",
  "photoId": "{uuidv4}",
  "timestamp": "{timestamp}"
}
```

Based on `user.photo-uploaded` event (and similar) I would like to know how many objects are getting created by users (total per day and per individual user).

---

How should I organize indices to store these events, so I can easily query them to extract the information that I'm interested in? Should I create a separate index for each event type? Should I group some events together? Or should I even use a single index for all of these events? Is my document structure correct or should I change it to something else?

What should be my reasoning in order to figure this out?

Answer (score 0):

This schema should work ok in general, and you can start with putting all events in one index. Import or create some fake data, index it and try to get the results you need with [ES aggregations](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations.html). As the dataset grows, you'll see the bottlenecks and resolve them.

They only caveat to take care of now would be to make sure you store all the fields that are used for aggregations as [keyword](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/keyword.html).